# If you have a List of strings called names, how would you set the 3rd name to the value "Totoro"?

Tags: java, list, collections

If you have a List of strings called names, how would you set the 3rd name to the value "Totoro" ?

Comment: [`set(index, value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-)

Answer (score 0):

The third element will be at index 2 since it starts from 0.

As commented, you can do:

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Anthony", "Jordan", "Westbrook", "Wade", "Bryant");

names.set(2, "Totoro");
System.out.println(names);
```

Output:

```
[Anthony, Jordan, Totoro, Wade, Bryant]
```